# python "zip" and for cycle to create an object

Tags: python, sorting, object, zip, cycle

I have just learn the zip command in python and I would like to exploit it for the topological sorting. However, I have still some problem with my code.

I have this python script for the topological sorting:

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Graph:
    def __init__(self, directed=False):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)
        self.directed = directed

    def addEdge(self, frm, to):
        self.graph[frm].append(to)

        if self.directed is False:
            self.graph[to].append(frm)
        else:
            self.graph[to] = self.graph[to]

    def topoSortvisit(self, s, visited, sortlist):
        visited[s] = True

        for i in self.graph[s]:
            if not visited[i]:
                self.topoSortvisit(i, visited, sortlist)

        sortlist.insert(0, s)

    def topoSort(self):
        visited = {i: False for i in self.graph}

        sortlist = []

        for v in self.graph:
            if not visited[v]:
                self.topoSortvisit(v, visited, sortlist)
```

I have also my csv file:

```
name;id;linked;distance;type
A;1;4;60807.66;N
B;2;3;50949.67;N
C;3;4;39067.50;N
D;4;5;48169.93;N
E;5;0;0;N
```

As I have just learnt from another post I do the following:

```
dfm = pd.read_csv(fname, sep=';',index_col=None, header = 0)
zipl  = zip(dfm['id'], dfm['linked'])
```

According to dfm['id'], dfm['linked'] I would like to sort them. Consequentially, I create the Graph object as:

```
links = Graph(directed=True)
```

and to sort them:

```
[links.addEdge(row) for row in zipl]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: addEdge() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'
```

I have no problem if I do:

```
links.addEdge(4, 5)
```

Is this a problem about data type?

Comment: `links.addEdge(*row)`

Comment: Could you explain me the difference between using 'rows' and '*rows'?

Comment: *rows is using the unpack operator.  So if rows had two elements, links.addEdge(*rows) is equivalent to links.addEdge(row[0], row[1]).  [Explanation](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558)